# How do I change server script background in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, user-interface, customization

I'm developing **Asp.net MVC** applications and since there's quite a bit of in-place server scripts in my aspx/ascx files it can become really messy finding your way around.

What I would like to do (to make things easier on me) is set some background colour to server-side scripts.

Right now only `<%` and `%>` have yellow background, but I would like **the content between these two** to also have a certain background colour. Something similar that Tengible's T4 editor does in T4 files with template [executable code](http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/T4-Editor-Visual-T4-Editing.html).

**How do I do this if at all possible?**

***A sidenote***
*This is not related to Asp.net MVC in particular but to Visual Studio in general. It will benefit Asp.net MVC developers the most though.* :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without addins this is **impossible**. No such setting in Visual Studio 2008 environment (or 2010 for that matter either).

Answer (score 0):

You did not specifically say whether you wanted to avoid doing this with third party tools. It might be possible to do this with [DevExpress CodeRush!](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/) tool. I have not looked into their custom macro support.

Comment: Legit answer. True. I didn't specifically say I want to achieve this addin-less. Because I think that is not at all possible.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it is possible, but I recommend opening the Tools / Options dialog, and in there looking around in Environment / Fonts and Colors. There is a "HTML Server-Side Script" item in the list, but I think it is just for the <% and %> tags.

Perhaps you should consider writing a VS Extension for this purpose. (For VS 2010, it is even easier to make one.)

Comment: I've checked those setting before already and yes they are related to `<%` and `%>` tags only... No setting for content between them...

Answer (score -1):

Go to tool -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Format -> tag Specific Option -> ASP.NET Controls. In this section it provides all the tags, you can change the tag which you like.

Comment: I'm not able to configure `<% %>` server side script section. I added them manually, but there was no obvious effect in the text editor whatsoever. Have you tried it?

Comment: You can change the color of <% %> tag by doing this-
Go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts & colors -> 
From the display items: select 'HTML Server-Side Script' & change the background and forecolor. But i don't know how to change the inner text color.

Comment: Exactly what I am talking about here. You can only change the display of the `<%` and `%>` but not for the content between these two.